# What am i missing in test class?

Tags: java, junit

I keep getting the error (java:cannot find symbol Symbol: method getType())

public class Shape {

Comment: `Shape.ShapeType.getType();` belongs to the `Shape` class **not** the `ShapeType ` class.  Also, it is not static, hence you need to instantiate a `Shape` first

Comment: Aren't i already instantiating Shape in the second line of the ShapeTest class?

Comment: second line comes after first line, which is where the problem is.

Comment: ah okay. I switched them. But it "Cannot resolve the method getType", even though I have it defined in Shape.

Comment: edit (add to) your question with the new code

Comment: *I switched them* is not enough.  Read my first comment and the answer below.

Comment: please see my edited Test class. What am i missing

Comment: so read my first comment - what do you not understand about my comment?

Answer (score 0):

`getCircleRadius` and `getType` methods are on the `Shape` class, but you're code references `Shape.ShapeType.getCircleRadius`

you need to reference `getCircleRadius` on a `Shape` instance, probably created with `new Shape(ShapeType,double)`

Comment: What about the getType() method? Compiler says I cannot instantiate an enum? Also, even after referencing getCircleRadius on a Shape instance, the test fails...(java.lang.AssertionError: Use assertEquals(expected, actual, delta) to compare floating-point numbers, at ShapeTest.getCircleRadius(ShapeTest.java:15)

Comment: `getType()` is also on the `Shape` class, so you do the same thing with that.

Comment: Also, since you're dealing with `double`s you should use `assertEquals(5.0, shape.getCircleRadius(), 0.0001)` or some other very small delta. You don't expect floating points to be exact when doing calcualtions, usually.